# autoLayout resize buttons for Retina 3.5/4"

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, resize, autolayout

I have a view with buttons optimized for iPhone 4. The buttons fill the whole screen. If the user have a phone with retina I want the buttons to still fill the screen. If the user have a iPhone 4 the buttons height are 148, but if the user have an iPhone 5 the buttons should now be 178...

iPhone 4:
http://i966.photobucket.com/albums/ae148/fostom/ScreenShot2013-08-17at94846AM.png

iPhone 5:
http://i966.photobucket.com/albums/ae148/fostom/ScreenShot2013-08-17at100649AM.png

Comment: - (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
use this line then tell me here whether it works or not?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the question, but if I understand, to change size the same button for different devices, you must explicitly change size of the button in your code.

Comment: the whole point of autolayout is that you don't have to explicitly change the size of UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I fixed this myself.

The solution for resizing the buttons from 3" screen to 4" screen is:

1. Select top row buttons. Set constraint ´Top Space To Superview´
2. Select bottom row buttons. Set constraint ´Bottom Space To Superview´
3. Select all buttons. Set constraint ´Heights Equally´

At least; this fixed my problem/question. This is purely done in storyboard and no code.

Comment: How can u edit top/bottom spaces to SuperView..? It is not editable

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with a constraint like this:

```
@"V:|-10-[button1]-5-[button2(==button1)]-5-[button3(==button1)]-10-|"
```

You don't specify the explicit height of the buttons, you tell autolayout that all buttons should have the same height (`button2(==button1)` means that button2 should have the same height as button1). Then you specify the distance between the buttons (5 in the example) and the distance between the top edge of the first button, the bottom edge of the last button and the edge of the view (10 in the example).

et voilà:

[image][image]

If you want to set up your constraints in interface builder you have to convert them yourself. Shouldn't be that much work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Sorry, but I have no idea how to implement that in code. Was hoping to set it in the storyboard. But this should be doable in the storyboard as well, right?